# Clearing selection in QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I'm using `PyQt4` and I have a `QListWidget` in a window where I added items to it at run-time. I want to use a button in the window to clear the selection of the `QListWidget`.

I want to know if there is any approach to achieve this?

I checked `clear()` but it clears the items in the listwidget, but I want to clear the selection in the listwidget.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [`setItemSelected()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlistwidget.html#setItemSelected)

Here is a working example of a listWidget with a "clear" button:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, random

def clear(listwidget):
    for i in range(listwidget.count()):
        item = listwidget.item(i)
        listwidget.setItemSelected(item, False)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
top = QtGui.QWidget()

# list widget
myListWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(top)
myListWidget.setSelectionMode(2)
myListWidget.resize(200,300)
for i in range(10):
    item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem("item %i" % i, myListWidget)
    myListWidget.addItem(item)
    if random.random() > 0.5: 
        # randomly select half of the items in the list
        item.setSelected(True)

# clear button
myButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Clear", top)
myButton.resize(60,30)
myButton.move(70,300)
myButton.clicked.connect(lambda: clear(myListWidget))
top.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Use [list_widget.selectionModel().clear()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#clear) or [list_widget.clearSelection()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#clearSelection) (thanks, @ekhumoro!).

I modified example by Junuxx:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, random

def clear(listwidget):
    #listwidget.selectionModel().clear()
    listwidget.clearSelection()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
top = QtGui.QWidget()

# list widget
myListWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(top)
myListWidget.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
myListWidget.resize(200, 300)
for i in range(10):
    item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem("item {}".format(i), myListWidget)
    myListWidget.addItem(item)
    if random.random() > 0.5: 
        # randomly select half of the items in the list
        item.setSelected(True)

# clear button
myButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Clear", top)
myButton.resize(60, 30)
myButton.move(70, 300)
myButton.clicked.connect(lambda: clear(myListWidget))
top.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The `QListWidget` class inherits `QAbstractItemView`, so you can just do: `myButton.clicked.connect(myListWidget.clearSelection))`.